# Das Gegenteil von 'verbalisieren'

Tags: single-word-request, antonym

Ich suche einen Begriff, der das Gegenteil von 'verbalisieren' ausdrückt.

> in Worte fassen, mit Worten zum Ausdruck bringen

<sub>["verbalisieren" laut Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/verbalisieren)</sub>

Dementsprechend suche ich einen Begriff für den Ausdruck in Textform, also in etwa:

> in Textform fassen, textuell ausdrücken

'Textualisieren' klingt vernünftigt, gibt es laut Duden aber nicht. Existiert solch ein Begriff? Falls nicht, was wäre die einfachste/kürzeste Beschreibung? Ich suche eine solche Vokabel, um zu beschreiben, wie ein lokaler Dialekt in Textform wiedergegeben wird. Danke!

Comment: Ich bin nicht sicher, ob es sich bei dem gesuchten Wort um das Gegenteil von "verbalisieren" handeln würde - ist denn das gesprochene Wort wirklich das Gegenteil des geschriebenen? Trotzdem eine interessante Frage.

Comment: @Hulk Hm, das stimmt. Schwierige Frage, kann ich nicht aus dem Stehgreif beantworten. Denke aber trotzdem, dass klar geworden ist, welchen Begriff ich suche.

Comment: Falls aus dem Kontext wenigstens ansatzweise klar ist, dass es sich um eine Niederschrift in irgendeiner Form handelt, finde ich "verbalisieren" immer noch besser als alle bisher genannten Alternativen und gebe @Hulk recht, dass dieses Verb die Schriftform absolut nicht ausschließt.

Comment: Ein Text kann auch gesprochen werden und, wie Hulk und Tofro schreiben, ist schreiben eine Form von Verbalisieren, sprachlich ausdrücken. Womit die Antwort schon gegeben ist: Das Wort für Schreiben ist Schreiben. Als ich nur die Überschrift kannte hoffte ich *zeichnen* schreiben zu können. Oder pantomisch präsentieren.

Comment: In deinem speziellen Fall (einen Dialekt möglichst lauttreu aufschreiben) würde ich dir hier tatsächlich "**transkribieren**" empfehlen. Wenn nur ein Wort bzw. ein Ausdruck für das schreiben bzw. schriftlich festhalten gesucht wird, wäre das aber falsch, da es eben eine speziellere Bedeutung hat. Hier würde man "**verschriftlichen**", "schreiben" oder "**schriftlich festhalten/wiedergeben**" nehmen. _(Wichtig ist natürlich noch, dass "verbalisieren" **nicht** "aussprechen", sondern "in Sprache fassen" bedeutet)_. Ich hoffe, dass ich hiermit die Antworten gut und sinnvoll zu einer

Comment: ... zusammengefasst habe!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ich würde hierfür **transkribieren** verwenden. Das entspricht zumindest meinem Verständnis der Anforderung *„…zu beschreiben, wie ein lokaler Dialekt in Textform wiedergegeben wird.“*

[Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/transkribieren):

> Bedeutungen:
>   [1] Linguistik: die lautgetreue Übertragung von gesprochener Sprache, Gesprächen oder Gebärden in eine schriftlich fixierte Form (beispielsweise Lautschrift)
>   [2] Linguistik: die lautgetreue Übertragung eines Textes in ein anderes Alphabet

[Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/transkribieren):

> 1. a. (Sprachwissenschaft) in eine andere Schrift übertragen, besonders Wörter aus einer Sprache mit nicht lateinischer Schrift oder Buchstaben mit diakritischen Zeichen mit lautlich ungefähr entsprechenden Zeichen des lateinischen Alphabets wiedergeben
>      b. (Sprachwissenschaft) in eine phonetische Umschrift übertragen

Answer (score 10):

Mein Vorschlag wäre *verschriftlichen*.

Comment: Existiert laut Duden auch nicht. Der Duden ist zwar nicht das Ende aller Weisheit, aber ich bin mir auch nicht sicher, ob *verschriftlichen* tatsächlich den von mit angestrebten Sinn trifft. Also etwas verbal geäußertes inklusive seiner Idiosynkrasien in Schriftform fassen; vllt findet sich dafür noch ein besserer Begriff.

Comment: Das Wort wird in der Ethnologie, Linguistik usw. in jedem Fall verwendet, ob Duden es nun kennt oder nicht. Mein Duden (25. Aufl.) kennt aber zumindest "Verschriftung (das Verschriftlichen)".

Comment: Wie wäre es mit [verschriften](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/verschriften)?

Answer (score 3):

Weniger wissenschaftlich, aber wie wäre es mit "niederschreiben"?

Oder die poetische, wenn auch auf ein bestimmtes Medium verweisende Floskel

> Etwas zu Papier bringen.

Andere Umschreibungen:

> Etwas schriftlich festhalten/wiedergeben.

Comment: Und was ist mit "aufschreiben"...? Nur so mein spontaner Einfall.

Answer (score 2):

Das Antonym von *verbalisieren* ist für mich eher "einen Gedanken nicht in Worte fassen" oder "nicht formulieren", "nicht aussprechen". Ich verstehe, dass du das nicht suchst.

*verbalisieren* sagt überhaupt nichts darüber aus, ob die Worte, zu denen die Gedanken nun formuliert wurden, mündlich oder in Schriftform (oder gar: überhaupt) wiedergegeben werden.

Falls du findest, dass *verbalisieren* zu sehr "aussprechen" impliziert, finde ich, dass das einfache *formulieren*, dass zwar ebenfalls Wort und Schrift offen lässt, schon ein bisschen näher an der "Schriftform" ist.

Answer (score 0):

Im Gegensatz zum Verbalisieren, also dem verbalen oder wörtlichen Beschreiben eines Vorgangs oder einer Handlung durch die mündliche Rede kann man auch eine im Wortsinne schriftliche Beschreibung / Umschreibung verwenden.

Answer (score 0):

Das Verb "verbalisieren" hat zwei verschiedene Bedeutungen. Daher ist die deine Frage nicht ganz klar.

Zu der ersten Bedeutung:*(etwas in Worte fassen)* Mann könnte zum Beispiel sagen, dass er/sie ihre Worte nicht **auf die Lippen bringen** konnte. Es besteht auch die Möglichkeit zu sagen, dass jemand seine Gedanken **nicht zum Ausdruck bringen** kann. Auch ist es möglich zu sagen, dass jemand versucht, seine Worte mithilfe der **nonverbalen Kommunikation zu formulieren**. Außerdem könnte man auch sagen, dass obwohl die Eltern ihre Sorgen **nicht sprachlich geäußert** haben, haben die Kinder instinktiv gespürt, wie es ihnen geht, **ohne dass es ausgesprochen wird**. Du kannst auch natürlich die verneinten Formen von **"artikulieren"** und **"dokumentieren"** verwenden, die eine bildungssprachliche Anwendung haben.

Zu der zweiten Bedeutung: (*ein Verb aus der Form einer anderen Wortart, meist einem Substantiv, bilden*)

> Beispiel: Verbalisieren sie die folgenden Nomen-Verb-Verbindungen.

Das Gegenteil von **"verbalisieren"** in diesem Sinne ist **"nominalisieren"**